# Как создать jar файл с помощью Maven в Eclipse

Tags: java, maven

Я так понимаю надо запустить команду:

```
mvn install
```

В IDEA я открывал terminal и  там набирал эту команду и все.
А в Eclipse чет не получается:
установил плагин terminal TX, запускаю эту команду, но вылетает ошибка:
"mvn не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным"

Answer (score 0):

То что не работает из консоли означает, что mvn не находится в переменной окружения `PATH`. сконфигурируйте ее в вашей ОС и будет работать.

Но еще удобней использовать плагин M2Eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/. Установите его (если он уже не установлен в комплекте) и после это можно будет запускать мавен через run/debug configuration, т.е. обычные команды Run/Debug, при этом будут работать горячие клавиши и т.д.

В меню Run -> Run Configurations ...

[image: maven run configuration]

Comment: так вроде как пишут, что плагин идет по умолчанию в eclipse или это другой плагин?

Comment: Зависит от версии. В Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2019-12 идет в комплекте.

Comment: как в этом eclipse все сложно, запустил build на что мне сразу выдал ошибку:
No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources....

Comment: я так понимаю, теперь надо в помник добавлять какие-то зависимости?

Comment: из консоли получилось запустить mvn install
вот только jar-файл не запускается, вот строка запуска:
start C:\Developer\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe --module-path C:\Developer\JavaFX\11\lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar %1

Comment: В предположении, что проект собирается в принципе мавеном, зависимости не нужны. Вы goals задали в конфигурации maven build? Если так ругается, то похоже что нет.

Comment: Что касается запуска, это уже другой вопрос совсем. Собраный обычным образом запускается? Т.е. это проблема настройки проекта мавен вообще или именно этого способа сборки (во что я не верю, честно говоря)?

Comment: не запускается ни каким образом. Т,е. пробовал через export делать, тоже самое файл не запускается, что-то с библиотеками, а что не пойму. Как понять где копать? Создал маленький проект на javaFx, он сразу же запустился

Comment: Комментарии неподходящее место, чтобы это обсуждать. Нужен новый вопрос конкретно про это с описанием, кодом и т.д.